# Why I see duplicated resolutions values in the dropdown ui after changing resolution?

Tags: unity, c#

When I'm running the game then in my graphics settings when I expand the options they are all duplicated and I can scroll down but the scrolling is very slow with the mouse wheel.

And it happens only in the build when building the game and running the exe file.
In the editor the items are not duplicated.

[image: Resolutions duplicated]

This is the script I'm using to get the resolutions values and assign them to the dropdown ui :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class Settings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
    public TMP_Dropdown resolutionDropdown;
    public TMP_Dropdown qualityDropdown;
    public Text musicText;
    public Text sfxText;
    public Slider[] audioSliders;
    public Toggle fullScreenToggle;

    private Resolution[] resolutions;

    private void Awake()
    {
        resolutionDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<int>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("resolutionvalue", resolutionDropdown.value);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));

        qualityDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<int>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("qualityvalue", qualityDropdown.value);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));

        fullScreenToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<bool>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("fullscreen", boolToInt(fullScreenToggle.isOn));
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        qualityDropdown.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("qualityvalue");

        resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
        resolutionDropdown.ClearOptions();

        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        int currentResolutionIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height;
            options.Add(option);

            if(resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width &&
                resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
            {
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
            }
        }

        resolutionDropdown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropdown.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("resolutionvalue", currentResolutionIndex);
        resolutionDropdown.RefreshShownValue();

        float musicvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicvolume");
        float sfxvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("sfxvolume");

        musicText.text = musicvolume.ToString();
        sfxText.text = sfxvolume.ToString();
        audioSliders[0].value = musicvolume / 100f;
        audioSliders[1].value = sfxvolume / 100f;

        fullScreenToggle.isOn = intToBool(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("fullscreen", 0));
        
    }

    public void SetResolution(int resolutionIndex)
    {
        Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionIndex];
        Screen.SetResolution(resolution.width, resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
    }

    public void SetMusicVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("musicvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        musicText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    }

    public void SetSfxVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("sfxvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        sfxText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("sfxvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    }

    public void SetQuality(int qualityIndex)
    {
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }

    public void SetFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen;        
    }

    int boolToInt(bool val)
    {
        if (val)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    bool intToBool(int val)
    {
        if (val != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution. I give a link for the solution because there are two ways to do it and I used the second one.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1463609/screenresolutions-returning-duplicates.html

Comment: Please include a description of the solution you used, so users who have this problem in the future can learn from this post even if the link rots.